# How to display 1000 of records in jsf page on scrolling

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I have 1000 records in my domain objects (java pojo classes) which I fetched from web services call. Now I need to display that record in front end page but not all the records in single shot. I want to show like when user scroll down the hidden data has to bee displayed to the user. eg. Facebook.

Note: All the records has to pre-loaded and when user scrolls down it has to display like facebook app.

Technology I'm using: Java backend, JSF, jQuery (front ends with webflow)

Comment: and where are you stuck? What about any infinite scrolling plugin?

Comment: Yet to implement. Which way would be best for that?

Comment: Try primefaces extensions like [this one](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/waypoint/infiniteScrollingOne.jsf) or [this one](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/waypoint/infiniteScrollingTwo.jsf)